# how to create tooltip with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tooltip

i try to create tooltip using jquery ui.

but when i try to `var_dump` i got nothing.

here my code

```
<a href="#"><span id='11111_22222'>text_here</span></a>
```

and here my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initialize tooltip
    $( "span" ).tooltip({
        track:true,
        open: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.tooltip.css("max-width", "600px");
        ui.tooltip.css("max-height", "340px");
              var id = this.id;
              var split_id = id.split('_');
              var image = split_id[1];
              var title = split_id[0];
              $.ajax({
                  url:'tooltip.php',
                  type:'post',
                  data:{image:image, title:title},
                  success: function(response){
                      // Setting content option
                      $("#"+id).tooltip('option','content',response);
                  }
              });
        }
    });

    $("span").mouseout(function(){
        // re-initializing tooltip
        $(this).tooltip();
        $('.ui-tooltip').hide();
    });

});
```

my tooltip.php code

```
var_dump($_POST);
exit();
```

result is `Array(0) {}`

Comment: You can check the Network panel in the browser's Developer Tools (press F12 to open) to verify the request payload.

Answer (score 0):

im fix this problem with change `POST` TO `GET`

from `type:'post',` to `type:'get',`